# Invalid datalabels position in latest version

Tags: highcharts

In version 3.0.5 I had this chart [code](http://jsfiddle.net/QBX9H/)

In version 3.0.6 I have this chart [code](http://jsfiddle.net/K7KjC/)

Does any one knows how can I have in 3.0.6 the same behaviour has 3.0.5

```
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible bug, reported to our developers here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2338